# High-precision timer in Android JNI

Tags: android, profiling, java-native-interface

I'm trying to profile my JNI application. Is there something like "Get ticks since startup" that I can use to measure functions and/or systems? Anything with the precision of 1/10 of a millisecond will do.

Obviously, a fully native function would be nicer, I'd prefer not to call a Java function for every single thing I'm trying to profile, but if that's the only option, I'll take that too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

clock_gettime().  You'll see sample code in android-ndk-r5b/samples/hello-neon/jni/helloneon.c and android-ndk-r5b/samples/native-plasma/jni/plasma.c.

You want to look for something like CLOCK_MONOTONIC to make sure you're getting ticks since startup, not the wall clock.

Comment: There was a suggestion (and an edit) that gettimeofday would work here.  It wouldn't; the problem is that gettimeofday is changed if the clock changes.  You're not going to get ticks since startup in that case.  (Think daylight savings, for one.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and/or

```
System.nanoTime();
```

I don't think either of those are time since startup, but they are both millisecnond timestamps that you may be able to use.

Comment: Sorry Tim, you've been out-answered by James :)